# Custom Alert creating Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented

Tags: ios, swift, xib, uialertview, uialertcontroller

Good Day,

I want to create a custom alert for gather information from the user.  However, it will not load and crashes with the following code:

xib file

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class WorkoutAlert: UIView {
    
    static let instance = WorkoutAlert()
    
    @IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var alertView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func workoutTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        parentView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("WorkoutAlert", owner: self, options: nil)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func commonInit () {
        
        alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        parentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        parentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        
    }
    
    func showAlert(title: String) {
        self.titleLabel.text = title
        
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(parentView)
    }
    
// MARK: - End of Code
}
```

Relevant code for the ViewController using the xib:

```
class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController {    

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
                                
        WorkoutAlert.instance.showAlert(title: "Add a new workout")
    }

}
```

Constraints for the xib

[image]

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.  I'm a novice and have found many ways and examples for creating alerts instead of using the standard alert controller.

Comment: Shouldn't you call `init(frame:)` ? Your alert has no size? `instance = WorkoutAlert()` is `instance = WorkoutAlert.init()`, ,not init(frame:)

Comment: Why are you creating a singleton instance for `WorkoutAlert`? That seems like a very bad idea to have a singleton for a `UIView`. Also, you should be implementing `init?(coder:)` instead of throwing a `fatalError` from it, since you're clearly calling it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement init methods according to your needs. But better to implement boths and you don't need singleton pattern here

```
class WorkoutAlert: UIView {
    
  
    
    @IBOutlet var parentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var alertView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBAction func workoutTextField(_ sender: UITextField) {
        
    }
    
    @IBAction func datePicker(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
        
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        parentView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    
    @IBAction func doneButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
    }
    
   
    
   required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
           super.init(frame: frame)
           commonInit()
       }
    
    private func commonInit () {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("WorkoutAlert", owner: self, options: nil)
        alertView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        parentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
        parentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        
    }
    
    func showAlert(title: String) {
        self.titleLabel.text = title
        
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(self)
    }
    
// MARK: - End of Code
}
```

In your controller

```
class WorkoutViewController: UIViewController {    

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
                                
      let alert =  WorkoutAlert(frame: self.view.bounds) // or can set frame here WorkoutAlert(frame: frame here)
      alert.showAlert(title: "Add a new workout")
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not crashing now but it freezes after addButtonPressed.

Comment: are you giving it frame ? or applying constraints ?

Comment: I'm applying constraints.

Comment: or can you share demo project to test and debug ?

Comment: I edited the question to add in the constraints use for the xib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218767/discussion-between-jawadali-and-be-know-do).